# Synchronize Sharepoint Group to Active Directory Group

Tags: active-directory, groups

How could I synchronize a SharePoint group with an Active Directory Group. It should all the time show the same users from SharePoint Group in Active Directory Group.

Comment: Are we talking here about SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server?  If it's online than the answer is no.

Comment: Sharepoint Enterprise.

Comment: And Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: So you are using on-premises SharePoint, not SharePoint online, right?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using AD groups directly in SharePoint? They are a lot easier to manage, and you can assign permissions to them, the same way as you were using SharePoint groups.

Comment: But how could I add user to AD Group by Javascript ?

Comment: They aren't all quite the same. SharePoint can take hours to recognize changes to a user's AD group change. Also, workflows can't expand tasks inside an AD Group. That said, there is no native way to replicate Group Membership changes to the AD, needs to be implemented.